# Confirm message in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I wrote this statment in my code:

```
Response.Write("<script language=javascript>confirm('The system not allow negative inventory,continue?');</script>");
```

how can I handel if the user clicked "Ok" or "Cancel" button?

Answer (score 2):

You should put this confirm to your submit button like that :

```
btnSubmit.Attributes["onclick"] += 
    "return confirm('The system not allow negative inventory,continue?');"
```

If user click cancel, your page won't be postback.

But if you ask you can determine user's action at server side, the answer is no, not directly. You should add some trick, to get the user's action. Maybe you should set the user's action into a hidden field and at server side get this value and continue.

Comment: ok but i don't want the confirm to appear at button click,
because in button click I do some calculation the I decide if I want to show the confirm message or not

Answer (score 2):

Restricting my answer to Javascript and not how the result of your code would interact with the flow of the page, the Javascript `confirm` method returns the value of the user's selected option:

```
var result = confirm('The system does not allow negative inventory. Continue?');
if (result == true)
  // The user wants to continue. Proceed accordingly.
else
  // The user does not want to continue.
```

You can use the value to branch your logic accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

That code will execute on the client side. To know if the user clicked OK or cancel on the server, you will need to make your script send a request back to the server. You can't handle the dialog in the same request, because your code will have ended before the user sees anything in their browser.

You could output JavaScript like this:

```
location.href = 'Handler.aspx?confirmed=' + confirm('Do you want to do X?');
```

This will send the browser to either `Handler.aspx?confirmed=true` or `Handler.aspx?confirmed=false`.

Answer (score 0):

On the onClientClick tag (in the aspx file) u can write

```
confirm('your message');
```

and onClick tag reference it to function in code-behind where you can write the function which will only be executed on OK click of the messagebox.

Using a javascript confirm function it is possible to allow a user to confirm or canel a button click. If the user presses yes on the message/alert box the button click even will be triggered on the server. If the no button is click no event will be triggered. This is especially useful with buttons used for deleting.

```
button.Attributes("onclick") = "javascript:return " & _
                 "confirm('Are You Sure you want to do this operation?') "
```