# How to show the delete confirmation dialog box in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In asp button click event, We have to validate the data entered in UI and has to ask the confirmation before save the changes.

How can i do that in asp.net web application?

Comment: Similar to this question, and the answer is the same:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118295/confirm-message-in-asp-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118295/confirm-message-in-asp-net)

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you using?  Also, are you using the ASP.NET AJAX in your application?

Comment: we are used .NET framework version 3.5

Comment: we are used AJAX in my application

Comment: In asp button click event, We have to validate the data entered in UI and has to ask the confirmation before save the changes.

How can i do that in asp.net web application?

Comment: It's a bit tougher if you want to validate and then ask the confirmation, especially if you need server side validation.  It might be easier to just ask for confirmation prior to validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also place the appropriate attribute within the markup:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Text="Delete" ImageUrl="button.gif" AlternateText="Delete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?");'/>
```

As Jason mentions, I think trying to get validation prior to the dialog box could be tricky.

Comment: awesome; worked perfect. But then how would I change the ok and cancel buttons? I'm interested in changing "ok" to "Yes" and "Cancel" to "No" Thanks in advanced for all your help. P.S. I'm a novice; I'm making a web application. for this particular function; I'm trying to delete an entry out of a database. I'm successful, just would like to know how to change the buttons. Thanks for all your help in advanced